# Find conditional expectation given conditional and marginal density

Tags: conditional-expectation, bivariate-distributions

If the conditional density of $Y$ given by $X=x$ is given by

$$f(y/x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
\binom{5}{y} x^y (1-x)^{5-y} & \mbox{if $y = 0,1,2,...,5$};\\
0 & \mbox{otherwise}.\end{array} \right. $$

and the marginal density of $X$ is

$$f_1(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
4x^3 & \mbox{if $0<x<1$};\\
0 & \mbox{otherwise}.\end{array} \right. $$

then what is the conditional expectation of $Y$ given the event $X=x$?

Thank you, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What "conditional expectation of $Y$ given the event $X = x$" are you looking for? $E[Y\mid X = x]$? I fear this is what you are asking for but not what you are looking for. Please enlighten.

Comment: No. That was the exact question.

Comment: So, the marginal of $X$ is not relevant, you just want $E[Y|X=x]  = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y f_{Y|X}(y|x)dy$.  Well, I notice now that $Y$ seems to be a discrete random variable, in which case the "conditional density" given does not make sense, it should be a "conditional mass function," so you want $E[Y|X=x] = \sum_{i=0}^5 i P[Y=i|X=x]$.